# WMI Remote Process Cannot Query Parent (Access Denied)

Tags: c#, .net, f#, wmi, win32-process

I have a .NET process that delegates work to other servers by creating a remote worker process on those servers and then sending the work over a TCP port.  That all works fine, but I would like the remote worker processes to 'monitor' the parent process on the original machine in case it is terminated abnormally (crash, reboot, etc) so that the worker processes can self-terminate in those scenarios instead of becoming 'orphaned'.

The parent process uses WMI to start the remote workers (it actually starts a CMD.EXE with a specific command line to run the worker so that I can capture the stdout/stderr to logs), and they seem to run as the same user on both hosts.  That user is a local administrator on both servers.  However, the remote process gets an Access Denied error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)` when it tries to run a `SELECT * FROM Win32_Process...` query on the host machine of the parent process to see if it is still running.  Oddly, if I run the worker process manually from a command line on the remote machine as the same user, it works.  It only fails when it is started remotely via WMI.

How can I ensure the child processes terminate when the parent itself is abnormally terminated and cannot gracefully shutdown the worker processes?  Is is possible to make the WMI query work from the child process with a different level of impersonation/authorization, or do I need to implement some kind of a heartbeat system over the TCP channel that's used to send commands?

For reference, here is the WMI code used by the parent to create the worker processes (this is F# but using the same mechanism one would use from C# or any other .NET language):

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Management

module Wmi =
    let connect host privileged =
        let options = ConnectionOptions(Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate, EnablePrivileges = privileged)
        let scope = new ManagementScope(sprintf @"\\%s\ROOT\CIMV2" host, options)
        do scope.Connect()
        scope

    let getClass className scope =
        let objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions()
        let managementPath = new ManagementPath(className)
        new ManagementClass(scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions)


module Win32Process =
    let private getCommandLine executable arguments =
        //Example: CMD.EXE /S /C " "c:\path\to\program.exe" "argument1" "argument2"  > "c:\path\to\stdout.txt" 2> "c:\path\to\stderr.txt" "
        let workerName = arguments |> List.tryFind (fun arg -> arg |> like "-n *")
        let stdOut, stdErr = 
            workerName 
            |> Option.bind (fun name -> name.Split(' ') |> Seq.tryLast)
            |> Option.map (fun name -> sprintf "%s.stdout.log" name, sprintf "%s.stderr.log" name)
            |> Option.defaultValue ("stdout.log", "stderr.log")
        let args = arguments |> String.join " "
        sprintf "CMD.EXE /S /C \" \"%s\" %s  > \"%s\" 2> \"%s\" \"" executable args stdOut stdErr

    let create host executable arguments =
        let scope = Wmi.connect host true
        let processClass = scope |> Wmi.getClass "Win32_Process"
        
        let commandLine = getCommandLine executable arguments
        let inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create")        
        inParams.["CommandLine"] <- commandLine
        inParams.["CurrentDirectory"] <- (FileInfo executable).Directory.FullName

        let outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null)
        let processId = outParams.["ProcessId"] |> unbox<uint>

        Process.GetProcessById(int processId, host)
```